# Is there an R package to import VSAM files as a tbble or dataframe?

Tags: r, import, vsam

I am looking for ways to process VSAM files with R and export as a csv.

I have been searching the web and have not been able to find any methods of using R to read VSAM files.

Answer (score 0):

A little more information would be of use.  How are you going to get the data from the VSAM files?  Are you reading directly from an IBM system?  What access method will you be using?  What is the structure of the file you are reading since since if you want it to be put in a data.frame, is it something like a CSV file already?.  So any other particulars would be helpful.